# how to find value with path x Groovy

Tags: xpath, groovy

please advise how to find and output cust_JiraTaskId. I need the value of cust_JiraTaskId based on the max number of  inside node   . In this example it'll be 111111.

I managed to find the max externalCode and now i need cust_JiraTaskId value.

```
<SFOData.cust_JiraReplication>
<cust_HRISId>J000009</cust_HRISId>
<externalCode>7</externalCode>
<cust_JiraTask>
  <externalCode>3</externalCode>
  <cust_JiraTaskId>12345</cust_JiraTaskId>
</cust_JiraTask>
<cust_JiraTask>
  <externalCode>5</externalCode>
  <cust_JiraTaskId>111111</cust_JiraTaskId>
</cust_JiraTask>
</SFOData.cust_JiraReplication>
```

My script is below

```
// Create an XPath statement to search for the 
 element or elements you care           about:
XPath x;
x = XPath.newInstance("//cust_JiraTask/externalCode");
myElements = x.selectNodes(doc);
String maxvalue = "";
for (Element myElement : myElements) {
if (myElement.getValue() > maxvalue)
{
   maxvalue = myElement.getValue();
}
}
 props.setProperty("document.dynamic.userdefined.externalCode", maxvalue);
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Groovy 2.4.5:

```
def xml = """
<SFOData.cust_JiraReplication>
<cust_HRISId>J000009</cust_HRISId>
<externalCode>7</externalCode>
<cust_JiraTask>
  <externalCode>3</externalCode>
  <cust_JiraTaskId>12345</cust_JiraTaskId>
</cust_JiraTask>
<cust_JiraTask>
  <externalCode>5</externalCode>
  <cust_JiraTaskId>111111</cust_JiraTaskId>
</cust_JiraTask>
</SFOData.cust_JiraReplication>
"""

def xs = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def nodes = xs.cust_JiraTask.cust_JiraTaskId

def maxNode = nodes.max { it.text() as int }
assert 111111 == maxNode.text() as int
```